# Auto login to migrate minecraft account

Tags: php, html, minecraft, account, migrate

I am currently trying to code a program for my website but i'm trying to log in automatically to mojang so they can migrate faster, and make sure their MC account is safe. However when I try to automatically log in to Mojang for migration it gives me the error: Authentication failed.

I know someone else tried this and succeeded but that was coded in JAVA, I want to make this with HTML.

```
<form action="https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check" method=POST target=_blank>
<input type="text" name="mcusername">  
<input type="text" name="password">
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" name="authenticityToken" value='.$token.'>';
?> 
<input type=submit value="Migrate Account">
</form>
```

I tried using the Token I grabbed from mojang.com/migrate using this code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://account.mojang.com/migrate');
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$fullstring = $file;
  $fullstring = str_replace("/migrate/check", "https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check", $fullstring);
$token = get_string_between($fullstring, '<input type="hidden" name="authenticityToken" value="', '">');
```

However, this returns an error when I press: Migrate account. I think I need to do something with cookies or Auth tokens. If any of you have an idea.. Please tell me

Comment: Try to set these in quotes `method=POST target=_blank` such as `method="POST" target="_blank"`

Comment: That won't change anything. I still get the error: Bad authenticity token

Comment: Yes I know, it's just a quick suggestion. Plus I doubt your `https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check` in your functions are valid. Try an actual file name and not a folder.

Comment: Not found

POST /migrate/check/ The original code also uses /check str_replace("/migrate/check"

Answer (score 1):

The token you retrive with your script is generated for your server and not for user submiting  html form. You have to get your token with Javascript.

BUT

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load https://account.mojang.com/migrate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://yourdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So I dont think you will be able to auth client with html/php .